# iOS 5 - Images within labels?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I'm sure there's going to be an easy answer for this, but I can't suss it out since I'm still new to iOS/Objective C.

I have a tableview with some cells that I'm populating with custom labels. I know how to fill the labels with things like

```
label.font
label.text
etc
```

But how can I put images inside of a label? Ideally, I need to find a loop that will let me put multiple images (like star ratings - some will have 1 star, others 3, etc) in a single label.

Help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
UILabel * tLable = [[UILabel alloc]init];
tLable setFrame:CGRectMake(<#CGFloat x#>, <#CGFloat y#>, <#CGFloat width#>, <#CGFloat height#>)];
for (int t = 0 ; t< numImages; t++) {
        UIImageView * image = [UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(<#CGFloat x#>, <#CGFloat y#>, <#CGFloat width#>, <#CGFloat height#>)];
        [image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:<#(NSString *)#>]];
        [tLable addSubview:image];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is an excellent answer and exactly what I needed! The key was the last line and adding a subview to the label. I didn't know that was possible and that's exactly what I needed here.

Answer (score 1):

To use custom images use a `UIImageView` and add it as a subview of your cell or the label.

Answer (score 0):

In order to put an actual image into a UILabel would be quite involved and would require you to subclass uilabel and override the drawrect method. Instead I would add a uiimageview to your cell where you want the image

Answer (score 0):

You need to use UIImageView instead of images inside of a label.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't. The `UILabel` class has no support for images. To achieve what you're looking for, will require you to build a custom view, which can be a composite of a series of `UIImageViews`.

There are a number of ways to achieve this:

1. create a NIB file with an empty view and layout your images inside it. Load an instance of it in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method and add it to the appropriate place in your cell.
2. create a class that derives from `UIView`. Override the `initWithFrame` method and create,position and add the `UIImageView` instances to it in that method. Expose some properties that allow you to set the image contents externally.
3. Create a class that devices from `UITableCellView` and configure it appropriately.